# Make one of two fields required in GraphQL schema?

Tags: graphql, graphcool

Im using Graphcool but this may be a general GraphQL question. Is there a way to make one of two fields required?

For instance say I have a Post type. Posts must be attached to either a Group or to an Event. Can this be specified in the schema?

```
type Post {
  body: String!
  author: User!
  event: Event // This or group is required
  group: Group // This or event is required
}
```

My actual requirements are a bit more complicated. Posts can either be attached to an event, or must be attached to a group and a location.

```
type Post {
  body: String!
  author: User!
  event: Event // Either this is required, 
  group: Group // Or both Group AND Location are required 
  location: Location 
}
```

So this is valid:

```
mutation {
  createPost(
   body: "Here is a comment",
   authorId: "<UserID>",
   eventId: "<EventID>"
  ){
    id
  }
}
```

As is this:

```
mutation {
  createPost(
   body: "Here is a comment",
   authorId: "<UserID>",
   groupID: "<GroupID>",
   locationID: "<LocationID>"
  ){
    id
  }
}
```

But this is not:

As is this:

```
mutation {
  createPost(
   body: "Here is a comment",
   authorId: "<UserID>",
   groupID: "<GroupID>",
  ){
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use an union type, however this question [is not solved](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/blob/master/rfcs/InputUnion.md). My preference goes to the @oneOf directive and the related [TS equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62591230/typescript-convert-a-tagged-union-into-an-union-type)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way you can define your schema to define groups of inputs as required -- each input is individually either nullable (optional) or non-null (required).

The only way to handle this type of scenario is within the resolver for that specific query or mutation. For example:

```
(obj, {eventId, groupID, locationID}) => {
  if (
    (eventID && !groupID && !locationID) ||
    (groupID && locationID && !eventID)
  ) {
    // resolve normally
  }
  throw new Error('Invalid inputs')
}
```

It looks like in order to do that with Graphcool, you would have to utilize a custom resolver. [See the documentation for more details](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/functions/resolvers-su6wu3yoo2).

Answer (score 4):

One way to represent this in the schema is to use [unions](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types) , in your case it could be something like this:

```
type LocatedGroup {
  group: Group!
  location: Location!
}

union Attachable = Event | LocatedGroup

type Post {
  body: String!
  author: User!
  attachable: Attachable!
}
```